# Determine if column is numeric in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a column that contains a variation of numbers, text or a combination of both.

I'm looking for a Power Query function that can identify is the column contains a numeric value.

| Id | [column] | Is numeric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | False |
| 2 | 44345 | True |
| 3 | C5133 | False |

So my query will read...

If [Column] is numeric then True, else false.

I've tried lots of functions, none work

Comment: Have you tried to research the forum, there was a solved query: **[Look_Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37960196/8162520)**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
Value.Is(Value.FromText([Your Column]), type number)
```

[image]